# Efficient way of processing huge Datatable in C#.net

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a huge dataTable (around 500k-600k rows). I wanted to compute rows based on some specific columns.
Ex: I have 3 columns name ID, type and value. I wanted to compute 'value' column based on 'Type'. I have done it using DataRow Filter - first get the unique 'ID', then for each 'type' compute value. This logic gets really complex and take longer to process. I'm not very good in LINQ, so i was wondering if i can do it better using LINQ or any other way?

DataTable:

```
ID       type      value  
--------------------------------
2         100         5

2         100         6

2         200         10

3         200         8

3         200         9

4         100         10

4         200         15
```

The output i'm looking for is:

```
ID     Type          Value

2       100            11

2       200            10

3       200            17

4       100            10

4       200            15
```

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by compute? Are you summing the value column based on the type, etc.?

Comment: sorry, yes i need to sum up 'value' column based on 'type'.

Comment: Okay, thought so. See my answer or some of the other answers.

Comment: First, avoid loading up a datatable/object collection with this many records if at all avoidable and process closer to the data source (database). Second, if you are only summing the values, and you do have to load them into memory, try using PLINQ to parallelize the processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this. Obviously, where I've used `<int>`, you would need to replace with proper types as appropriate.

```
var output = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
             let id = row.Field<int>("ID")
             let type = row.Field<int>("type")
             group row by new { id, type } into grp 
             select new 
             {
                 ID = grp.Key.id,
                 Type = grp.Key.type,
                 Value = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("value"))
             };
```

This is going to result in rather simple *code*, but it should not arguably be more *efficient* than a well written loop (and, of course, if you can offload this to the database instead, you will generally be better off). However, all things held equal, Linq code is pretty well optimized and efficient. If you have doubt about efficiency, **measure**. Run both your existing code (if you have it) and code from answers and see where you stand.

Comment: can you add performance reference to your answer (dpac mention he has quite large data..)

Comment: @Delashmate: Added performance measurement to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718190/efficient-way-of-processing-huge-datatable-in-c-net/7718511#7718511)(VB.NET, but doesn't make a difference).

Answer (score 4):

Why not do it in SQL?

```
select id, type, sum(value) from TABLE group by id, type
```

Comment: This is great example that demonstrate a case which SQL is much more simple than LINQ

Comment: Although this might be the the best answer(if applicable), it actually does not answer the question on how to do it with a DataTable.

Comment: True - I assumed that the data came originally from SQL, and that would be the most efficient place to do this.  But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

VB.NET(if anybody is interested):

```
Dim groups = From r In tbl
             Group r By IDTypes = _
             New With {Key .ID = CInt(r("ID")), _
                       Key .Type = CInt(r("Type"))}
                  Into Group
             Select New With { _
                    .ID = IDTypes.ID, _
                    .Type = IDTypes.Type, _
                    .Value = Group.Sum(Function(grpRow) (CInt(grpRow("Value"))))}
```

Here is test-data:

```
Dim tbl As New DataTable
Dim row As DataRow
Dim rnd As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Int32)))
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Type", GetType(Int32)))
tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Value", GetType(Int32)))
For i As Int32 = 1 To 1000000
    row = tbl.NewRow
    row("ID") = 2 * Rnd.Next(0, 6)
    row("Type") = 100 * Rnd.Next(0, 6)
    row("Value") = 5 * Rnd.Next(0, 11)
    tbl.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

---

Time-Measurement for 1.000.000 Rows:

```
watch.Start()
Dim execute = groups.Any()
watch.Stop()
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", _
                                        watch.Elapsed.Hours, _
                                        watch.Elapsed.Minutes, _
                                        watch.Elapsed.Seconds, _
                                        watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10))
```

Results (on 2,26 GHZ Xeon, 24GB) :

1. 00:00:00.61
2. 00:00:00.58
3. 00:00:00:63

~600 Milliseconds for 1.000.000 Rows grouped+totalized to ~36 "ID-Types"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're looking to do some sort of grouping, with an aggregate of some sort on the value column, you can do something like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

var results = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new { Type = row.Field<int>("Type") } into groups
              select new
              {
                  Type = groups.Key.Type,
                  TotalValue = groups.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Value"))
              };
```